# FCP retime timelapse image gets blurry

Tags: video, editing, framerate, 4k

If i retime (speed up) my 4k footage, the image gets blurry.
If i stop the movie, i see a crispy still image!
Why?

I already tried to slow time the footage but it doesn't work

Thanks

Comment: It's unclear. Please provide more details. With what tool do you retime?

Comment: i retime with the retime button inside finalcut pro

Comment: Did it happens after rendering (export), or in the editor? If in the editor, then it is just for faster showing to you result. Try to export video end see result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you retime the images so that there are more than one images that can land on a frame, your video software will likely interpolate between the two by blending the two frames.  If you play back at 12 fps with zero offset, your video software should play the first image for two frames (assuming 24fps playback), then the second frame for two frames, etc.  If you play back starting with a one frame offset, the first image will play for one frame, then a blend of the 1st and 2nd image will play the second frame, then a blend of the 2nd and 3rd image will play the third frame, then a blend of the 3rd and 4th image will play the fourth frame, etc.  That image blending will make the film look blurry.

Alternatively, say you have 240 frames and you want to play them at 24fps, but you are asking the editor to play them all in 1 second instead of 10 seconds, the video editing software might not pick every 10th image and display it for one frame, but will instead blend 10 images and play that as a frame.  That could also account for the blur.

Comment: i solved it! it was the display performance/quality setting to performance instead of quality!

Comment: @LorisClara but of course!

Comment: @LorisClara Could you put this solution in an answer - possibly describing where the settings are in the app or with pictures of the windows you used? Thanks!